# Setting App Icon depending on build configuration for WinRT

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, manifest

I have built a WinRT app.

When i run it using Debug, i would like it to have a different icon for when i run it in release.

Can this be done?

Comment: When you say "icon," are you referring to the app's tile on the Start screen? Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? You can only have one version of a given app installed at a time, so if the thought was to have the debug and release versions side by side, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what i want. I really hope that is not true, as the release will be used by everyone at my work (including me) but i will still need to run development versions side by side with released.

Comment: @devhammer you can install applications side by side, you only need to change the Package name in the manifest file to make it so. I now have my build script swap out the images and suffix the package name with "Live" or "Debug"

Comment: I'd argue that what you're doing in that case is a workaround that essentially creates two versions of the app. If that suits your needs, great. Definitely something I'd limit to test environments, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is a pre-build step.  Let's say you set up your assets directory like:

```
Assets
    Debug
        logo.png  // debug version of logo
    Release
        logo.png  // release version of logo
    logo.png      // location of logo provided in app manifest
```

in a pre-build step (via the Properties of the project) you could then use the following command:

```
 copy "$(ProjectDir)Assets\$(ConfigurationName)\logo.png"  "$(ProjectDir)Assets" /Y
```

Answer (score 1):

This also looks like a viable option, and could prove more powerful, not only will i be able to change the images, but i will also be able to manipulate the package name (for side by side loading) and also anything else in the manifest (small things like background colour).

[Example: How to Change Manifest Information by Using a Post-Build Event
The follo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)